# Jackson Deserialize an Object in different way depending of the context

Tags: java, json, jackson

In my application, imagine I can create an Animal Object :

```
public class Animal {
    private int id;                                                                                                                                                                       
    private String food;
    private String comment;

    // Getter and setters
}
```

From somwhere in the app we create lot of Animal object and they are stored into the database.
Animal can also be created from JSON, so if I receive

```
{
  "id":123456,
  "food":"biscuit",
  "comment":"black with white pows"
}
```

A new Animal will be created in database.

Now imagine we want to put that Animal into Zoo.

```
public class Zoo {
    List<Animal> animals = new Arraylist<>();

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

The Zoo can be constructed by Json. But here we don't want to receive the full Json for every Animal, but just their Id because they already exist into the database.
we will receive something like :

```
{
  "animals": [
    {
      "id":123456
    },
    {
      "id":987654
    }
  ]
}
```

So we have two case, in the first case Animal are the root element of the Json we receive all the fields and store it into the database.
In the second case Animal can be into a list or just a child of another object and we receive only is Id to load it from the database during the deserialization.

So my question is, how from a custom deserializer, I can verify if the json I try to deserialize is a root Animal or a child animal ?

I'd like to write something like that :

```
public class ReferenceDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Animal> {

    @Override
    public Animal deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectCodec oc = jp.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jp);

        if (I have a root Animal)
        {
            deserialize the full animal
        } else if (I have a List or a Animal which is not a root object)
        {  
         load the Animal from database with the id received
       } 
      return myAnimal:
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to verify if it's a root or child animal. Instead verify if the node contains only `id` key or it has more fields.

Comment: Because I can't assure I will always receive an objet with only an id.
Even if I continue to receive a list with all animal datas, I still want to retreive animals from my database.

So when I first ask all animals from the server I need to deserialize them in a classic way, then saving them into the database.
Then when I will receive another objets that contains animals (whatever only the id or all datas are specified) I want to get them back from database.
Annotations can be useful, but I'm looking for a generic solution through module configuration /custom deserializer.

Comment: @Codebender I tried your solution, so I check if there is only the uuid then I load by reference, this part works, but if I have to deserialize the full entity I do mapper.treeToValue(jsonNode, MyObject.class);
But that cause an infinite loop because the treeToValue re call my deserializer again and again and again. Any solution to avoid this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` annotation above the class definition. By this, only the id field of the `Animal` object will  be populated and you don't have to use Custom deserializer.

Comment: The problematic is not to deserialize an object when all fields are not defined.
But to be able to deserialize an object in a different way in function of the case:
- The first time when the application will connect to the server it will get all animals in a classic way.
- Then for all objets using an animal we will get it back from database instead. So only the id is necessary to get it back from DBB.